# how to upgrade an iPod 5.0 to 5.1 (and not to 6.0) for development purposes?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

We would like to target iOS 5.1 and above.
We have one device with iOS 6.0 and one with iOS 5.0.
Is there a way (without jailbreaking) to upgrade the iOS 5.0 to iOS 5.1?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it possible to just download the iOS 5.1 ipsw from somewhere [Here for instance](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-5.1-ios-for-iphone-4s-4-3gs-ipad-and-ipod-touch-direct-links/) and just install it via iTunes by holding the alt-button and clicking restore and then selecting your ipsw-file?

Comment: @Guy : the link provided is pretty reliable. You won't have any trouble installing the ipsw from there.

Answer (score 0):

It might still be possible, as long as Apple is still signing iOS 5.1, which I think they are. Go here: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=757

Then, just do these steps.

Once you have 5.1.1 firmware

1. Open iTunes
2. For Mac; click option/restore in Itunes and select 5.1.1 firmware you just downloaded and confirm restore.

Hopefully that will work. Worst case scenario, iTunes tells you that you can't upgrade. But I believe that should still work. But you better move fast.